# "libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work" when starting thin on Debian

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debian, thin, libv8

I am using thin as development web server with Rails on Debian 7. Since I've updated Rails to 4.2.7.1 I cannot launch thin anymore and I'm getting this error message :

```
Using rack adapter
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
Aborted
```

I have a `libgcc_s.so.1` file in my `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` folder but somehow thin cannot seems to find it there.

I have tried every answer [to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/382150/installing-32bit-gcc-on-debian-squeeze-x64) but it didn't help.

EDIT: I think the problem is related to the `libv8` gem, that is a dependency to my project. The error shows when the default `5.3.332.38.1 x86-linux` version of the gem is used. But if I force it to version `5.0.71.48.3 x86-linux`, the error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the library for the right architecture:

```
apt search libgcc1
```

E.g. Try installing `apt install libgcc1-amd64-cross` (or `libgcc1-x32-cross`).

In `/lib/i386-linux-gnu` you've libraries for i386 binaries, so most likely you're missing libgcc1 for x86_64.

```
$ dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
libgcc1:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
$ dpkg -L libgcc1:amd64
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
```